# Access Most Recently Used (MRU) entries via Python on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, pywin32

Using Python, is it possible to get access to the Most Recently Used (MRU) list in windows. This is where Windows keeps a list of the most recently opened documents and programs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible: yes, easy yes.
the challenge though is choosing *which* MRU to choose from... windows and programs stores dozens of em - windows alone probably stores 6 of them.
presuming you want the Windows run dialogue you can get it like so (Python 2x syntax, tested on python 2.7):

```
def get_run_mru():
    import _winreg
    regKey = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
        r'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU')
    recent = _winreg.QueryValueEx(regKey,'MRUList')[0]
    recent_list = []
    for subkey in recent:
        recent_list.append(_winreg.QueryValueEx(regKey,subkey)[0])
    return recent_list
```

Of course then you'll have to do whatever you want to do with that but that should get you started.

Pacific

Comment: Forgot to mention: just search the registry/Google for the other registry locations of MRU lists and depending on how they are stored there just edit the code as needed of course.